# Cannot get Slack connector to work from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, slack

I'm sending this from Jenkins to Slack:

curl -X POST -H Content-type:application/json --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://slackUrlHere/services/T270E10SK/BN5940TK4/m9jpmWBcK7clCG5P0enAJK4G

That line is from the console log in Jenkins.

I get the following error:

Failed to connect to SlackUrlHere port 443: Connection timed out

If I copy that same line from the console log and paste it into an Ubuntu terminal running in the WSL on the same machine it works fine, I get "OK" back and "Hello, World!" in Slack.  Same thing in Postman.  Only Jenkins fails.

This is the line from the Jenkins file:

def response = sh(script: "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data '{\"text\":\"Hello, World!\"}' https://slackUrlHere/services/T270E10SK/BN5940TK4/m9jpmWBcK7clCG5P0enAJK4G")

Thanks for any pointers.

-Jim

Comment: I'd consider logging into the jenkins box itself and trying the curl from there (maybe there's an outbound security policy in-place?).

Comment: Do you have a proxy setup to connect to outside internet? Looks like you do on the Jenkins server cause it complains about having no connection to slack api. Also, `REMOVE THE SLACK URL, ANYONE CAN FLOOD YOUR CHANNEL` if you leave it there

Comment: Thank you for that pointer on the URL, totally missed that.  Anyway, I can't really get on the Jenkins box directly, I need to reach out to another group on that (and I will).  On any other machine if I put in that URL I do get to the Slack API site..